# Save raster brick into a geotiff which can be viewed by image viewer

Tags: r, tiles, raster, gdal, rgdal

I want to crop my big geotiff files (4 RGBA bands) into smaller tiles. Function `brick` in raster package is used to read raster file, and `writeRaster` is used to write into disk. However, I cannot open the new file with image viewer. It is caused by missing ColorInterp tags.
I

```
a <- brick(old.tif)
writeRaster(a, filename = new.tif)
```

Compare the tiff tag in old.tif and new.tif. The tag BitsPerSample is 8 for old.tif and 64 for new.tif. So I updated the dataType in raster into `INT1U` which supposed to `0-255`.

```
 dataType(a) <- 'INT1U'
 writeRaster(a, filename = new.tif, dataType = 'INT1U')
```

However, the tag BitsPerSample still equal to 64. 
My current question is how should I specify the BitsPerSample into 8.

PS: This code is not working too

```
writeRaster(a, filename = new.tif, dataType = 'INT1U', BitsPerSample = 8)
```

PPS: `writeTIFF` can generate viewable tiff file without crs information.

Comment: Compare the tiff tag from the old and new file. The new file has BitsPerSample (4 Short): 64, 64, 64, 64, which should be 8.

Comment: Some image viewers don't correctly interpret multiband TIFFs, especially when the data type is higher than 8-bit unsigned. What are you using? Try opening it in QGis or similar.

Comment: I understand the image can be viewed in the QGis and other software. But my original tif file is RGBA and can be viewed by any image viewers. Just want to create new images with the same 8-bit.

Answer (score 1):

With GeoTiff, you do not need to specify the number of bits per sample unless you want to deviate from the base format. For example, you can specify 2 bits per sample with `GDT_Byte` (0-255) to reduce the file size for a boolean image. When it is read back in, it will be interpreted as `GDT_Byte` correctly (by most software).

However, if your data is already `GDT_Byte` (INT1U), it is not necessary to specify the number of bits per sample, it will default to the required size; the parameter expects values smaller than the "default", for example: 1 to 7 bits for a specified 8-bit format, 9 to 15 bits for a 16 bit format, etc.

See the documentation on the NBITS parameter for GeoTiff images here: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.

It also looks like `BitsPerSample` is not a valid argument to `writeRaster`, but that it should be passed as a creation option, as `options=c("NBITS=n")`, the same syntax as GDAL uses outside of R.

With regards to the colour interpretation tag you refer to, you can specify that in options: `options=c("PHOTOMETRIC=RGB")`. If there is an alpha channel, you can add `"ALPHA=YES"`. These are all standard creation options documented in the link above.